# Make setter method recursive in every 1 minutes duration

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I want to store minutes remaining count into the variable inside my class.

Have implemented setter method into the class, is working fine

I need to decrease the count by 1 after every 1 mins.

How can I add such recursion to setter method inside my class?

Comment: There is no need for recursion; just schedule a repeating timer and decrement the count

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(yourMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and add count logic in your method

Comment: will this work if my #selector(yourMethod) is a setter

Comment: I don't think so, try to put setter in yourMethod

Answer (score 1):

When you have done don't forget to `invalidate()` timer.

```
func remainsMinut() {
    minut = minut-1
   //update UI andother code
}

let timer : Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(self.remainsMinut), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```